# R-INLA: Random effect logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am trying to fit a random effect mix model using INLA, having previously attempted to fit using "glmer" under the frequentist approach. This failed to converge due to large number of random effects in my data.

The data comes from a case-control type study (1 = case, 0 = control), and a list of risk factors (x1, x2, x3 ...) were calculated for each samples. All variables were categorised into groups, and the data looks as follows:

```
res    age            breed   x1  x2  location
0      1 (0-1 yrs)    beef     1    1     A1
0      2 (1-2 yrs)    dairy    1    2     A1
1      1              beef     1    2     B2
0      1              beef     2    1     C1
1      3 (>3 yrs)     dairy     3    3     B1
1      2              beef      1    1     A1
0      3              beef      2    1     B4
...     ...                ...          ..    ..
```

There are around 20,000 data points with 9000 distinct locations. The INLA procedure I used is:

```
formula <- res ~ age + breed + x1 + x2 + x3 + f(location, model = "iid")
model <- inla(formula, data = data, family = "binomial", Ntrials = 1, control.compute = list(dic = TRUE, cpo = TRUE))
```

Results from standard logistic regression (excluding random effect) offers similar parameter estimates between "glm" and INLA, however when random effect is included in the model structure as above, parameter estimates (in the logit scale) increased by more than 2 times. This means that when interpreting the odds ratio, it increases exponentially (i.e. exp(parameter estimate)), which does not seems to make sense having an odds ratio of 40...

My question: is the INLA model specification ("iid") appropriate for this type of analysis? and if so, how do I interpret the results in terms of odds ratios between different risk groups? (using "rw2" seems to give reasonable estimates but I cannot interpret the random effect estimate under this approach)

```
Fixed effects:
                     mean     sd 0.025quant 0.5quant 0.975quant     mode kld
(Intercept)      -10.8871 0.4949   -11.8440 -10.8927    -9.9506 -10.9516   0
age_2               3.8959 0.3272     3.2739   3.8889     4.5581   3.8746   0
age_3               4.1865 0.3421     3.5346   4.1797     4.8772   4.1659   0
breedDairy         1.2053 0.1365     0.9393   1.2046     1.4746   1.2032   0
x1_2                 4.8721 0.4258     4.0498   4.8682     5.7156   4.8600   0
x1_3                 4.1444 0.3322     3.5055   4.1408     4.8039   4.1337   0
x2_2                -1.0174 0.2727    -1.5485  -1.0189    -0.4782  -1.0220   0
x2_3                 1.9669 0.4119     1.1570   1.9672     2.7744   1.9677   0

Random effects:
Name      Model
 location   IID model 

Model hyperparameters:
                                     mean     sd 0.025quant 0.5quant 0.975quant   mode
Precision for location 0.0621 0.0051     0.0536   0.0615     0.0734 0.0602

Expected number of effective parameters(std dev): 4174.80(49.56)
Number of equivalent replicates : 4.458 

Deviance Information Criterion: 7865.86
Effective number of parameters: 2875.54

Marginal Likelihood:  -5074.21 
CPO and PIT are computed
```

Many thanks for your help!

Best

s

Comment: are you sure the `glmer` model didn't converge and that it wasn't a false positive warning?  Can you post those results?

Comment: Yeah, although it is not an error message, but a warning saying model failed to converge, also the variance component for the random effect is way too large, and that is why I don't really trust the model outcome. Also tried doing this in SAS, failed to converge also. Hoping to get some meaningful results from INLA with the correct model specification.

Comment: Hmm.  Not obvious to me why INLA should fit much differently, unless you impose strong priors (which you can also do via the `blme` package). On the surface this doesn't look like a horribly difficult problem, I wonder what's bad about it ... maybe the distribution of location effects is wonky?  Have you tried putting in location-dependent covariates (e.g. a spatial trend model)?

Comment: Hi Ben, I think I may have the problem of "complete separation", because majority of my data at each location level contains either all 0's (controls) or all 1's (cases). I have tried to use "blme" with strong priors, this also gives wild estimates (huge odds ratios). Is the conclusion that random effect model is not appropriate in this case, and maybe standard logistic with over dispersion is the best solution here?